# C# HttpPostedFileBase.ContentType fails one string comparison, passes another

Tags: c#, arrays, string-comparison, httppostedfilebase

I'm trying to compare the content type of an `HttpPostedFileBase` against an array of acceptable types, and I'm encountering some genuinely odd behaviour.

`array.Contains()` can't find the string, but if I iterate over the collection and compare each entry to the string, it gets a match.

Here's my code:

```
string[] acceptable = new string[]{ 
    "text/comma-separated-values", 
    "text/csv",
    "text/anytext",
    "application/csv",
    "application/excel",
    "application/octet-stream",
    "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "application/vnd.msexcel"
};

string type = model.file.ContentType.ToLower().Trim();

string err = "acceptable.Contains(type) = " + 
             (acceptable.Contains(type) ? "true" : "false");

err += "<br/><br/>";

foreach (string s in acceptable)
{
    if (s == type)
        err += "but " + type + " is definitely in the string array!"; 
}
```

The code above outputs the following

```
acceptable.Contains(type) = false    

but application/octet-stream is definitely present in the string array!
```

If I copy and paste the printed value of `file.ContentType` into a string variable and run the comparison, it works fine. It only fails when reading the value directly from `HttpPostedFileBase.ContentType`, which is of type `System.String` by the way.

Comment: IF I run your code but replace `string type = model.file.ContentType.ToLower().Trim();` with string = "text/comma-separated-values". Everything works as expected.

Comment: Ben, I did mention that. See the end of the post.